# numpy.insert() is cutting off strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a column `column = [list of long strings]` that i would like to insert into a numpy array `table`.  After running `table = numpy.insert(table, 1, column, axis = 1)` and `print table`, I find that all the inserted elements from `column` have been truncated at the 70th character in `table`.  Do numpy arrays have a maximum length to the strings they can store in one element?  If they do, what's a way around this?

Comment: `numpy` simply cuts of the strings due to formatting. The strings should be OK ;-)

Comment: It sounds like `table` has a dtype of 'S70' or 'U70' - the strings in `column` are truncated when they're inserted into `table`.

Comment: @rayryeng printing out that element or writing it to a file only displays the first 70 characters.  The shape is (47, 6) which is what I expected.

Comment: @ajcr column is actually just a normal python list, but you're right, table's dtype is 'S70', is there a way around this?  I don't suppose i can just set it to 'S140' or something.

Comment: @Katana: yes you could create a new array with more space with `table = table.astype('S140')` (or as as large as it needs to be to hold the largest string in column). Any new strings up to that length can be inserted without being truncated.